# Overlaying a SVG/PNG file on top of ever-changing gradient background

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, svg, transparent

Here is the link of how it looks currently:
http://cubicfoundations.com

What I am trying to achieve:

[image: http://cubicfoundations.com/SCREENSHOT.png]

The gradient div acts as a background. The SVG image (logo div) overlays the gradient div with a full-width-and-height white background, showing the gradient colors through the transparent parts of the logo.

How do I achieve this?

I am also unable to assign a 100% height to the gradient div - it seems to only work on a fixed px basis?

Any fixes/ideas greatly appreciated!

**The HTML is:**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Cubic Foundations</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="js/index.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="gradient" />
  <div id="logo" />
</body>

</html>
```

**The CSS' path is css/style.css**

```css
body {
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
  background-color: #FFFFFF;
}
#gradient {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: -99999;
}
#logo {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: url(../cubic-logo-ws.svg) center center no-repeat;
}
```

Comment: for the 100% height, either use vh and vw units or set all your div's parents width and height to 100% (including html). for the other part of the question, I don't get it.

Comment: I have managed to fix the 100% height using the following code to #gradient:

     #gradient
     {
     width: 100%;
     height: 100%;
     padding: 0px;
     margin: 0px;
     position:absolute;
     z-index: -99999; 
     }

Comment: I do apologise for not being clear in my question. I have added a screenshot to show what I am trying to achieve: http://cubicfoundations.com/SCREENSHOT.png

Hopefully that helps!

Comment: You have several head, body and html tags intermixed/nested...

Comment: put the <img/> as an html element in the #logo, have the logo have a background:White;

Answer (score 0):

Your svg is wrong: re-make it only for the white part, without your margins.

Then, you will be able to fit it in an HTML container that plays a moving gradient.

Answer (score 0):

On browsers with HTML5, and IE version 10 and beyond, you can use flex containers.  The flex container is created by applying CSS attributes to your HTML elements that make them "smart" on layout, resizing, and filling their parent elements.

Here's a tutorial:

```
https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/
```

And here's a code generator:

```
http://the-echoplex.net/flexyboxes/
```